# Get Class to know a Variable

Tags: php, namespaces, global

I'm facing a problem, I want the class Page to know the Variable '$format'.

```
// class1.php
<?php

  include('./class2.php');
  echo $format->getTest(); // returns :-) (declared in class2.php)

  class Page {

    PUBLIC function getText() {
      return $format->getTest(); // returns Call to a member function getTest() on null
    }

  }

  $page = new Page;

?>
 // class2.php
<?php

  class Format {

    PUBLIC function getTest() {
      return ":-)";
    }

 }

 $format = new Format;

?>
```

Any suggestions/ideas?

EDIT:

I found a way: `return $GLOBALS['format']->getTest();`
But I dont like it, its so much to type. Any other way(s)?

Philip

Comment: [`$page = new Page($format);`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: how does this make `$format` known to `Page`?
Anyways, I got more Classes than just `Format`, is there another way without using a Constructor? I mean, I got the varibale in `class1.php` already, any way to get in in `class Page` also?

Answer (score 0):

Proper objective solution is to pass variable to constructor, setter or as argument to `getText()` method. Choose one you find most appropriate for your case.

**Constructor**

```
class Page
{
    private $format;

    public function __construct(Format $format)
    {
        $this->format = $format;
    }

    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->format->getTest();
    }

}

$page = new Page($format);
echo $page->getText();
```

**Setter**

```
class Page
{
    private $format;

    public function setFormat(Format $format)
    {
        $this->format = $format;
    }

    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->format->getTest();
    }

}

$page = new Page;
$page->setFormat($format);
echo $page->getText();
```

**Argument**

```
class Page
{

    public function getText(Format $format)
    {
        return $format->getTest();
    }

}

$page = new Page;
echo $page->getText($format);
```

Comment: Thank you! What do you think about this solution, I declare a constructor,  walk through `$GLOBALS` and declare a varibale with everything `$GLOBALS` contains?

Comment: Then what is a point in using objective code if you want hardcode everything? You will have class which always works in the same way no matter what you do (because it always read global variable). It's clearly not what you want, because (I presume) there will be new Formats in the future and you will want to replace one format with another.

Comment: no, format is one class out of many classes i got in a folder `/classes`. I'd like to implement every class I need by making them visible